# Solving circular dependency

Tags: c++, templates, circular-dependency

I know there are a couple of circular dependency issues out there, but I just couldn't solve this one.
I have two classes: `Manager` and `Managed`. `Manager` creates `Managed` objects and `Managed` basically wraps a couple of `Manager` methods and some of them are templated.

```
// Manager.h
struct Manager {

    Managed create(); // To be defined in the .cpp
    
    template <typename T>
    Managed create() {
        Managed managed(this); // Access Managed constructor
        managed.whatever<T>(); // Access templated function
        managed.whateverElse();
        return managed;
    }   
}

struct Managed {
    explicit Managed(Manager* manager) : manager(manager) {}
    
    template <typename T>
    void whatever() {
        manager->... // use the Manager pointer for whatever purpose
    }
    
    void whateverElse(); // To be defined in the .cpp

    Manager* manager;
}
```

It is a static library project, for any sake.
Also, real code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/MZiBRLzy).

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried `PIMPL` or forward declarations? 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

Comment: The question lacks details and clarity because it looks like you oversimplified your shown code. The first thing to change when struggling with dependencies is to move all implementation after all declarations, but in the shown code you did not, you implement the method inside the class. Do the implementation after the Managed class. Next is to provide forward declaration of all classes. I.e. start with `struct Managed; struct Manager;`. You state that you have checked many other questions, which should have made you aware of these basic steps. Something is hence inconsistent in your question.

Comment: Questions covers pretty much everything it would require to be answered, like you even did. I fowarded the declaration of them but did not provide on this snippet and moving the implementation right after the declaration is something I completely forgot about.

Comment: Does that mean my comment actually solved your problem? In that case I will turn it into an answer.

Comment: @IlianZapryanov never heard of PIMPL. I'll take a look, thank you!

Comment: Henri you asked for an answer splitting into two headers and cpp. Implementing templated classes or methods inside code files (i.e. non-headers) is not possible. If you still want two headers please create another question with details on this, I will be happy to try. Just not within the next 10 hours...

Answer (score 2):

I just reorder your code and used `PIMPL` then I build a small example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Managed;
struct Manager;

struct Managed {
    explicit Managed(Manager* manager) : manager(manager) {}

    template <typename T>
    void whatever() { }

    void whateverElse(); // To be defined in the .cpp

    Manager* manager;
};


struct Manager {

    Managed create(); // To be defined in the .cpp

    template <typename T>
    Managed* create() {
        Managed* m = new Managed(this);// Access Managed constructor
        m->whatever<T>(); // Access templated function
        m->whateverElse();
        return m;
    }
};
```

It can compile that way. But in any case should consider such designs better.

Comment: You changed the `Manager::create` signature. Also, I did not see any `PIMPL`. Also, what design would you suggest for this? The problem is that C++ doesn't support circular dependency, nor templated functions implementations in a cpp file.

Comment: This example _does_ use opaque pointers and is a solution to the circular dependency issue. Changing the signature is required because, when this translation unit is compiled, the compiler does not know the size of the depended-on struct. The pointer simply acts as a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to change when struggling with dependencies is to move all implementation after all declarations, but you implement the method inside the class. Instead do the implementation after the `Managed` class.
Next is to provide forward declaration of all classes. I.e. start with

```cpp
struct Managed;
struct Manager;
```

I will quote from Johns answer to provide more code details.
(John was kind enough to delete his answer when he realised that I wanted to turn my comment into one. Thanks. I quote explicitly, because I would seem like doing so implicitly anyway, writing extremely similar code.)
John kindly stated that compiling this is possible.

```
struct Managed;

struct Manager {

    Managed create(); // To be defined in the .cpp
    
    template <typename T>
    Managed create();
};

struct Managed {
    explicit Managed(Manager* manager) : manager(manager) {}
    
    template <typename T>
    void whatever();
    
    void whateverElse(); // To be defined in the .cpp

    Manager* manager;
};

template <typename T>
Managed Manager::create() {
    Managed managed(this); // Access Managed constructor
    managed.whatever<T>(); // Access templated function
    managed.whateverElse();
    return managed;
}   

template <typename T>
void Managed::whatever() {
    manager->create();
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to sepparate both classes into different header/cpp files? If so, please show how.

Comment: See my comment on your question.

Comment: @john I say it in my answer, but just to give you the deserved ping: Thanks.